# Strange window appears when battery is low

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-surface

When my battery got below 10% today, suddenly this window appeared at the right bottom of the screen:

[image]

The window does not react to any user input. It can't be removed or put to the background. I don't know which process to kill. First I suspected Adobe Creative Cloud, but the window was still there when I killed all Adobe processes.

How can I remove this window? Why is it here at all?

I know that my battery is low. I don't need a window blocking a screen part to remind me of my battery status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a Microsoft Surface specific thing. The window belonged to the process SurfaceDTX.exe, which seems to be some Surface specific process. No idea what it does. Killed and disabled.

Comment: For what it's worth, disabling SurfaceDTX may not be the best idea, because that's the software that interacts with the detach system to do it cleanly. You may end up in a situation where you're trying to detach and not know what specifically you'd need to close in order to detach (because elevated process).

Comment: @plttn Thanks for the info. Do you have a Surface Book? Have you ever seen this window when your battery was low?

Comment: Yes I do. I don't know the specific cause of this nor have I seen it, but given it's Adobe, I'm guessing you were most likely working in Photoshop or another Adobe program. Since the GPU is in the base, the program needs the base to stay powered otherwise the program will throw a fit.

Comment: Ah that might be the cause. Still very annoying that you cannot move or hide this window. What if the save button is hidden behind the window? Moreover, the window does not explain anything. *"... reveal the applications below to close"*. Adobe Desktop Service is not an application I know.

Comment: It's poorly written but it's basically saying reveal the program from the tray to close it.